# passing PIL image to OpenCV causes TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to apply CLAHE method using OpenCV library to the green channel which has been split, but then this error appears:

```
 cl = clahe.apply(multiBands[1])

TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
```

My code:

```
# Example Python Program for contrast stretching

from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv

 
# Method to process the green band of the image

def normalizeGreen(intensity):

    iI      = intensity
    minI    = 90
    maxI    = 225
    minO    = 0
    maxO    = 255
    iO      = (iI-minI)*(((maxO-minO)/(maxI-minI))+minO)

    return iO

# Create an image object
imageObject     = Image.open("input/IDRiD_02.jpg")

# Split the red, green and blue bands from the Image
multiBands      = imageObject.split()

# create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional)
clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
cl = clahe.apply(multiBands[1])

# Apply point operations that does contrast stretching on each color band
normalizedGreenBand    = cl.point(normalizeGreen)

# Display the image before contrast stretching
imageObject.show()
 
# Display the image after contrast stretching
normalizedGreenBand.show()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You passed a PIL Image to an OpenCV function. That's not supported.

Comment: OpenCV's python bindings often spit out this message. for a given parameter, various types may be accepted, but "UMat" is the *last* type in the list for this parameter... and it only reports that, not the other options.

Comment: PIL and OpenCV have different image formats. You must convert from one format to the other.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for answering, btw may I ask. In opencv, is there a function like poin() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL and OpenCV both have different formats of image objects but they can be interchangeable, e.g. OpenCV accepts ndarray and you can change PIL image into array using NumPy. Similarly, you can get PIL image object from numpy array using `PIL.Image.fromarray()` method. I've modified your code and I think it will resolve your issue.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Method to process the green band of the image
def normalizeGreen(intensity):
    minI, maxI = 90, 225
    minO, maxO = 0, 255
    iO = (intensity-minI)*(((maxO-minO)/(maxI-minI))+minO)
    return iO

# Create an image object
# imageObject = Image.open("<path-to-image>")
imageObject = Image.open("images/13/img-r1-000.jpg")

# Split the red, green and blue bands from the Image
r, g, b = imageObject.split()

# Apply point operations that does contrast stretching on each color band
normalizedGreenBand = g.point(normalizeGreen)

# convert the Pil Image object to OpenCv image object
normalizedGreenBand = np.array(normalizedGreenBand)

# create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional)
clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
normalizedGreenBand = clahe.apply(normalizedGreenBand)

# Display the image before contrast stretching
imageObject.show()

# convert the OpenCv image object to Pil Image object
normalizedGreenBand = Image.fromarray(normalizedGreenBand)
# Display the image after contrast stretching
normalizedGreenBand.show()
```

I first applied the `point()` method on the green channel and then converted the normalized green channel into a NumPy array in order to apply the `cv.createCLAHE()` operation. Finally, I reconverted the NumPy array into PIL image object for displaying (we can use `cv2.imshow()` without converting to PIL object).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! that's help me a lot. May I ask again. Do u know point operation function like PIL have in OpenCV?